# Solving IVP by integration

Tags: initial-value-problems

I need to solve this question:

> Consider the IVP $y' = f(x, y)$, for $f(x, y) = x \sin(y)$ and $y(0) = π/2$
>   for $x ∈ [0, 3] =: I$.
>
> Verify that $y(x) = π − \arctan ( 2 e^{x^ 2/ 2}/e^{x^2}-1)$  solves the IVP

Here is what I have so far:

Integrating on both sides, I get:

$\ln{\lvert\tan(y/2)\rvert} = {x^2 /2} + C$

$\tan(y/2) = e^{x^2} + C$

inserting $x=\pi/2$ and $y=0$ gives us, $C=0$

$y = (1/2)\arctan(e^{x^2} )$

I don't know how to proceed further to get

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), otherwise other users will not know what you mean (for instance, **what is your equation?** $y'=f(x,y)$?).

Comment: Oh sorry! Yes, it's y′=f(x,y)

Comment: You should plug the given solution into the equation and initial condition, and check if they are satisfied.